# How to add title, x axis label and y axis label while using .subplot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, data-visualization, visualization

I have a dateframe called `for_plot` and I am using the following snippet of code to make a bar diagram:

```
import matlplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,8))
x_1 = for_plot['res_code'] - 0.2
x_2 = for_plot['res_code']
pre = for_plot['n_indnota_pre']
post = for_plot['n_indnota_post']
ax.bar(x_1,pre, width = 0.2, color = 'red')
ax.bar(x_2,post, width = 0.2, color = 'green')
ax.set_xticks([0.9,1.9,2.9])
ax.set_xticklabels(['GEN','ST','SC'])
ax.legend(['pre_nota', 'post_nota'],loc = 1)

ax.xlabel('Constituency Type')
ax.ylabel('No of Independent Candidates')
ax.title('Average No Of Independent Candidates by Constituency Type')

plt.show()
```

I do understand how to work around with matplotlib but I have a few questions on the nuances:

1. What does `f` in line 1 of the snippet do? As the snippet stands, what do `f` and `ax` represent?
2. I am not able to add the axes labels and chart title (as in the last 4 lines of the snippet) using `ax.xlabel('Constituency Type')` but while drawing other figures, If I don't call `subplot()` in the first line and use `plt.xlabel('Constituency Type')`, it works absolutely fine. Why does it behave this way?

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xlabel'
```

Edit 1:

```
f.xlabel('Constituency Type')
f.ylabel('No of Independent Candidates')
f.title('Average No Of Independent Candidates by Constituency Type')
```

Doesn't work either.

```
AttributeError:'Figure' object has no attribute 'xlabel'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope below answer will help.

1. `f` represent `Figure` object which is the top level container for all the plot elements and `ax` is object or array of `Axes` objects (in your case its single object)
2. You can use code below for setting label and title of subplots:

   `ax.set_xlabel('common xlabel')
   ax.set_ylabel('common ylabel')
   ax.set_title('ax title')`